# Sizing elements to percentage of screen width/height

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, screen-size

Is there a simple (non-LayoutBuilder) way to size an element relative to screen size (width/height)? For example: how do I set the width of a CardView to be 65% of the screen width.

It can't be done inside the `build` method (obviously) so it would have to be deferred until post build. Is there a preferred place to put logic like this?

Comment: Just saying, this is generally not good practice IMO, that's web design stuff. In apps you should generally use device pixels to define sizes, and use Paddings to inset your widgets, since your aspect ratio is almost always the same (except for tablets).

Comment: After another 1.5 years, it seems like this isn't such a bad idea after all. Every month there's new phones coming out with weirder and weirder aspect ratio.

Answer (score 363, accepted):

`FractionallySizedBox` may also be useful.
You can also read the screen width directly out of `MediaQuery.of(context).size` and create a sized box based on that

```
MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.65
```

if you really want to size as a fraction of the screen regardless of what the layout is.

Comment: What if you need to get the width of the immediate parent widget?

Comment: This returns the size of the window rather than screen, ie on a system that supports windows this value will change as you resize the window rather than being a fixed value based on the screen's pixel count.

Comment: if i change the display size in from the phone setting, then the ratio set (0.65 in your example) might not be suitable...

Answer (score 431):

This is a supplemental answer showing the implementation of a couple of the solutions mentioned.

#### [FractionallySizedBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FractionallySizedBox-class.html)

If you have a single widget you can use a `FractionallySizedBox` widget to specify a percentage of the available space to fill. Here the green `Container` is set to fill 70% of the available width and 30% of the available height.

[image: FractionallySizedBox]

```
Widget myWidget() {
  return FractionallySizedBox(
    widthFactor: 0.7,
    heightFactor: 0.3,
    child: Container(
      color: Colors.green,
    ),
  );
}
```

#### [Expanded](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html)

The `Expanded` widget allows a widget to fill the available space, horizontally if it is in a row, or vertically if it is in a column. You can use the `flex` property with multiple widgets to give them weights. Here the green `Container` takes 70% of the width and the yellow `Container` takes 30% of the width.

[image: Expanded]

If you want to do it vertically, then just replace `Row` with `Column`.

```
Widget myWidget() {
  return Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
        flex: 7,
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        flex: 3,
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.yellow,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

#### Supplemental code

Here is the `main.dart` code for your reference.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("FractionallySizedBox"),
        ),
        body: myWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// replace with example code above
Widget myWidget() {
  return ...
}
```

Comment: Note that if you're building anything remotely similar to a progress bar, you'll likely want to set `FractionallySizedBox` constructor `alignment` parameter to `Alignment.centerLeft`, as the default is `Alignment.center`.

Comment: @Suragch, May be a dumb question, when we use `FractionallySizedBox`, what is the reference used to calculate height or width factor, is it total screen size or something else

Comment: @Shiva, I think it is the available space, not the total screen size. The available space is determined by the parent widget.

Answer (score 154):

This might be a little more clear:

```
double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

double yourWidth = width * 0.65;
```

Hope this solved your problem.

Answer (score 43):

There are several possibilities:

#### 1- The first one is the use of the `MediaQuery` :

**Code :**

```
MediaQuery.of(context).size.width //to get the width of screen
MediaQuery.of(context).size.height //to get height of screen
```

**Example of use :**

```
Container(
        color: Colors.yellow,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.65,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      )
```

**Output :**

[image]

#### 2- The use of  `FractionallySizedBox`

Creates a widget that sizes its child to a fraction of the total available space.

**Example :**

```
FractionallySizedBox(
           widthFactor: 0.65, // between 0 and 1 
           heightFactor: 1.0,
           child:Container(color: Colors.red
           ,),
         )
```

**Output :**

[image]

#### 3- The use of other widgets such as `Expanded` , `Flexible` and `AspectRatio` and more .

Answer (score 24):

You could build a Column/Row with [Flexible](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html) or Expanded children that have flex values that add up to the percentages you want.

You may also find the [AspectRatio](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AspectRatio-class.html) widget useful.

Answer (score 19):

There is many way to do this.

**1. Using MediaQuery :**  Its return fullscreen of your device including appbar,toolbar

```
 Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.50,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.50, 
        color: Colors.blueAccent[400],
 )
```

[image]

**2. Using Expanded :** You can set width/height in ratio

```
 Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.50,
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              flex: 70,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.lightBlue[400],
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 30,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.deepPurple[800],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
    )
```

[image]

3. Others Like  [Flexible](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html) and  [AspectRatio](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AspectRatio-class.html) and [FractionallySizedBox](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PEsY654EGZ0)

Answer (score 16):

First get the size of screen.

```
Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
```

After this you can get `width` and multiply it with `0.5` to get 50% of screen width.

```
double width50 = size.width * 0.5;
```

---

But problem generally comes in `height`, by default when we use

```
double screenHeight = size.height;
```

The height we get is global height which includes `StatusBar` + `notch` + `AppBar` height. So, in order to get the left height of the device, we need to subtract `padding` height (`StatusBar` + `notch`) and `AppBar` height from total height. Here is how we do it.

```
double abovePadding = MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top;
double appBarHeight = appBar.preferredSize.height;
double leftHeight = screenHeight - abovePadding - appBarHeight;
```

Now we can use following to get 50% of our screen in height.

```
double height50 = leftHeight * 0.5
```

Comment: This saved my life. Though, I must point out that the context (used by abovePadding) has to be the one from the appBar.

Answer (score 10):

```
MediaQuery.of(context).size.width
```

Answer (score 7):

you can use MediaQuery with the current context of your widget and get width or height like this

`double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width
double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height`

after that, you can multiply it with the percentage you want

Answer (score 7):

Use the LayoutBuilder Widget that will give you constraints that you can use to obtain the height that excludes the AppBar and the padding. Then use a SizedBox and provide the width and height using the constraints from the LayoutBuilder

```
return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context2, constraints) {
  return Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      SizedBox(
        width: constraints.maxWidth,
        height: constraints.maxHeight,
        ...
```

Answer (score 3):

**For width**

```
double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

double yourWidth = width * 0.75;
```

**For Height**

```
double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    
double yourHeight = height * 0.75;
```

If you don't want static height and width just use `Expanded` widget\

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatelessWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyStatelessWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Expanded Row Sample'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              flex: 2,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.amber,
                height: 100,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              height: 100,
              width: 50,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.amber,
                height: 100,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

if you are using GridView you can use something like Ian Hickson's solution.

```
crossAxisCount: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width <= 400.0 ? 3 : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width >= 1000.0 ? 5 : 4
```

Answer (score 2):

**Code :**

```
MediaQuery.of(context).size.width //to get the width of screen
MediaQuery.of(context).size.height //to get height of screen
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **Align** widget. The **heightFactor** and **widthFactor** parameters are multiplied by the size of the child widget. Here is an example that will make a widget with a fixed height in% ratio

```
         Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            heightFactor: 0.63,
            widthFactor: ,
            child: Container(
              width: double.infinity,
            ),
```

Answer (score 2):

Use scaler to define the layout width and height in percentage

```
dependencies:
      scaler: ^1.1.0+1
```

After setting this in **pubspec.yaml** you can use this by following the code -

```
import 'package:scaler/scaler.dart';
```

**Example After import use this -**

```
import 'package:scaler/scaler.dart';

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  /**
   * Container with 25% width of screen 
   * and 25% height of screen
   */
  return   Container(
      height: Scaler.height(0.25, context),
      width: Scaler.width(0.25, context),
      child: Container()
  );
}
```

To more detail about this

https://pub.dev/packages/scaler

Answer (score 1):

I am surprised that no one has yet suggested `LayoutBuilder` in 2023 which gives you access to the parent's width `BoxConstraints.constraints.maxWidth`, which is the most versatile method.

`Expanded` can only set the percentage of the available spacing, but what if you really want to set a percentage based on the actual parent's widget only, not the entire screen width, what if have a fixed width widget in a row, even a more complex, what if you also want an `Expanded` to expand the remaining `Row`.

`MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` is relative to the entire screen, not to the actual parent.

`FractionallySizedBox` works similarly but you can't put it in `Row`

Also, this method the perfect emulation of CSS % unit of measurement.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
        return SizedBox(
          width: 470,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                width: 200,
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.link,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: constraints.maxWidth*0.6,
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.message,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.phone,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),

              SizedBox(
                width: constraints.maxWidth*0.3,
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.account_balance,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    );
  }
}
```

In this example, we are setting a parent widget of 470 width with Row inside. In the Row, one element has a 200 fixed width, another with a 60% of the parent with 470, another with  30% of that same parent, and another expanding any remaining space.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly use a very simple trick

> Column(
> mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
> crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
> )

Comment: Simple Hack. Usefull

Answer (score 0):

Run this in the terminal

```
$ flutter pub add scaler
```

import this:

```
import 'package:scaler/scaler.dart';
```

then, this is an example:

```
import 'package:scaler/scaler.dart';

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  /**
   * Container with 25% width of screen 
   * and 25% height of screen
   */
  return   Container(
      height: Scaler.height(0.25, context),
      width: Scaler.width(0.25, context),
      child: Container()
  );
}
```