# Flutter differnt axis units

Tags: flutter

How do I deal with using multiple unit types (percentage of space, number of pixels, etc.) to size a widget? A CSS equivalent example is `div{width: 70%; height: 50px}`

Answer (score 0):

Could do something like this:

```
        Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.50, // this would be 50% of screen width
          height: 50,
        )
```

Another option would be:

```
        LayoutBuilder(
            builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
                return Container(
                  width: constraints.maxWidth * 0.50, // 50% of parent size
                  height: 50,
                );
            }
        )
```

More info at: [Sizing elements to percentage of screen width/height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43122113/sizing-elements-to-percentage-of-screen-width-height)