# How to create a multicolor Progress Bar with Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How can i create a multicolor Progress Bar in Flutter. I read about the LinearProgressIndicator but i am not sure it will suffice.

I want to do something like this.

[image: Text]

Please guide me on what widget to use. I do not want full code.

Comment: Check the link I added in the updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to assemble it part by part. I see five parts in the progress bar you show :

1. A grey rectangle with a shadow/depth effect, curved corners
2. Green rectangle with white text (read: Container with border)
3. Amber rectangle with white text
4. Red rectangle with white text
5. All the rectangles are horizontally (read: Row)

The numbers will be changing as your event(s) are progressing. Now, this can be achieved with setState(). So, lets' not worry about that. :)

Okay, as far the You need to prepare a class which takes one parameter and that's the `progressPercentage`. Based on the percentage, you decide how many blocks to show and with what text. [This](https://codepen.io/mcsukhi/pen/yLYbQLK) simple code snippet draws green rectangle with some text on it. And [this](https://codepen.io/mcsukhi/pen/NWGyBVW) codepen shows multi color bar which might be fairly easy to convert into the progressbar.

Answer (score 2):

I see that the answer had been given. However I have an alternative solution which can be easily generalized for any case. Here is the code that implements the author's image.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'MultiColor LoadBar Demo',
      home: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 50,
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                    flex: 50,
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.green,
                      child: const Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: Text('50', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white))),
                    )),
                Expanded(
                    flex: 25,
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.yellow,
                      child: const Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: Text('25', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white))),
                    )),
                Expanded(
                    flex: 10,
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.redAccent,
                      child: const Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: Text('10', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white))),
                    )),
                Expanded(
                    flex: 15,
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    )),
              ],
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

You can find a detailed explanation on how this works in [Sizing elements to percentage of screen width/height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43122113/sizing-elements-to-percentage-of-screen-width-height)